# Second display(displaylink USB) not updating right in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xserver, display-manager, displaylink

I'm still a bit new to Ubuntu,

I've got an Asus MD169B+ USB monitor that uses the DisplayLink driver and I've got a 1050 ti in my laptop. After a bit of fiddling I've got the driver to work but now I've got another issue. my Second monitor does not update right. It only updates if I move my mouse. An example for this is when I'm typing into the terminal it will not show me what I typed and what the terminal returned until I move my mouse on my second display and it only updates if I move.

What do I do and where should I even start?

this is how my x server display configuration looks like:

[x server display config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utWR6.png)

**Edit:**

*This is only when my display is in portrait mode.*

Comment: DisplayLink is a proprietary driver, so I would guess you should probably start by contacting their support line.

Comment: Please update your post with output of `lsusb` and `lsmod | grep -E "drm|video"`.